# Voltage regulator middle pin not soldered to the board

Tags: arduino, voltage-regulator

Today I noticed that my Arduino board only has two of the pins of the voltage regulator hooked up. I thought I understood how it worked, but I must be missing something.

Why isn't the middle pin hooked up to anything? Was it always like this or did I break it? The board seems to work just fine.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The soldered tab on the regulator chip usually connects to the middle pin and you can bet half a years wage on IT being connected to the circuit: -

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I had thought it was just a heatsink, but it is soldered to the board too. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There is a large tab on the other end of the regulator that is soldered to ground, and almost certainly also connected to the center pin.

From the board layout, I suspect that the regualtor is available both with and without the center pin, since there is a pad where the center pin would be soldered if it was on the package.

Comment: It's not connected to ground - it's the output pin on an L1117 regulator.

Comment: @Andyaka: I was thinking of the 78xx series, where the tab is ground - I should have just said "soldered to the board"...

Comment: Okay, I see that now. Thanks a bunch. I just thought the big tab at the top was a heat sink before.